# Error in WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:4502/Broker'

Tags: webrtc, xsocket

I am new in here,and I wrote this code but it gives error in console :'ws://127.0.0.1:4502/Broker' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.Can anybody help me ? I only try samples from internet but they don't work.

```
$(function () {

        ws = new XSockets.WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:4502/Broker");
}
```

Comment: Did you turn your XSockets server on ? Is it listening on port 4502 ?

Comment: How can I do it ? I am working on VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to start a XSockets server on localhost and port 4502 (default port for XSockets)
2. You have to have a controller named broker on in the server. By the connection string it looks like you are trying to connect to a very old version of XSockets. Probably v3.*
3. Since you are using the "broker" controller I assume that you are trying WebRTC (video/audio). If so... Take a look at this [video](http://xsockets.net/academy/xva-05-01-webrtc-basics) and download this [sample source code](https://github.com/XSockets/XVA/tree/master/XVA-05-01-WebRTCBasic) afterwards

Comment: @batuhan Can you please let us know what fixed the issue ?